# jquery find selects selected option within div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Trying to figure out how to get a selects selected option where there is no id or class to use as a selector, but is contained within a specific div (theres multiple selects on the page I only want this one).

Not sure if I should do something with find, parent, sibling, other...
Example of what I am working with.

```
<div id="mydiv">

<select name="myselect">
<option selected="selected" value="1">Hi</option>
</select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `>` symbol to select direct children. `:selected` returns selected options.

```
jQuery('#mydiv > select[name=myselect] > option:selected')
```

If you want all selected options use this:

```
jQuery('option:selected')
```

To get the `select` elements of those selected options:

```
jQuery('option:selected').parent();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select by name:

```
var val = $('select[name="myselect"]').val();
```

Here is a list of ways to select using jQuery (it's awesomely long): http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Since it's a child element you can also do this:

```
var val = $('#mydiv').children('select[name="myselect"]').val();
```

This starts with your DIV that has an ID, then gets the children of that element that are select element(s) with the `name` attribute set to `myselect`.

If your `select` element was not a direct descendant then you could use `.find()` instead:

```
var val = $('#mydiv').find('select[name="myselect"]').val()
```

Docs for ya:

- `.children()`: http://api.jquery.com/children
- `.find()`: http://api.jquery.com/find
- `.val()`: http://api.jquery.com/val

Note that calling `.val()` in a `select` element will return the `value` of the selected `option`.

Answer (score 0):

You can select it by name:

```
var sel = $('select[name=myselect]');
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `$('div#mydiv > select > option[selected="selected"]')`